# Android ExpandableListView getChildView not triggering

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I make an ExpandableListView following many tutorial and some error questions from SO.
The parent list consist of two TextView and an ImageButton with standard layout. The child list consist of single TextView.
The data source is from SQLite Database from activity and generate to ArrayList.

**The Problem :**

Somehow the parent group list works normally even the button works properly but when I try to expand, it wont expand. So I try to put some Toast message but after open the activity, but it looks like `getChildView()` method not triggering at all because the Toast message doesn't show at all.

The ExpandableListAdapter class is like this

```
public class InventoryListExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Inventory> data;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> list_data;

    public InventoryListExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Inventory> data, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> list_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.list_data = list_data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {return data.size();}

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {return list_data.get(data.get(groupPosition)).size();}

    @Override
    public Inventory getGroup(int groupPosition) {return data.get(groupPosition);}

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {return list_data.get(data.get(groupPosition).getCode()).get(childPosition);}

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {return groupPosition;}

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {return childPosition;}

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {return true;}

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            final Inventory inventory = getGroup(groupPosition);

            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.listview_layout_two_row_delete, null);
            ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            TextView text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

            text1.setText(inventory.getCode());
            text2.setText(inventory.getItem());

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout_single_text, null);
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "Make Child number "+String.valueOf(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TextView text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I appreciate for any help you give. Thank you.

Comment: if it is not called it probably because `getChildrenCount` is returning 0

Comment: I've checked it and the size isn't 0

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours trying to find the same issue, only to realise it was something dead simple on my side:

1. You have an ImageButton in the GroupView which is intercepting the touch to expand the view. Use this to fix it:

android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

2. Since the group view is not expanded, there is NO reason to waste CPU cycles to fetch a view that will not be displayed.
3. All of the methods in the adapter relating to the children is not called.

Try calling expandableListView.expandGroup(0...n) to manually expand it and see if it called the child-related methods in the adapter

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thank you so much. It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

I found a different way to have the getChildView() called when it is not automatically invoked in the ExpandedListAdapter class.It is a shortcut which somehow seems to solve the issue.I have a expanded list view with the parent group items being a list of check boxes.Clicking on the checkboxes displays the child items. Here is how i coded the getGroupView() function.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) m_context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_milk_type,null);
    }
    final CheckBox cbMilkType = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_milk_type);
    cbMilkType.setText(m_listMilktype.get(groupPosition));

    cbMilkType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)viewGroup;
            cbMilkType.toggle();
            if (!isExpanded) {
                expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            }
            else {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**change hasStableIds Method**

```
  @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {return false;}
```

**Please change your getGroupView Method :: **

```
 @Override
 public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            final Inventory inventory = getGroup(groupPosition);

            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.listview_layout_two_row_delete, null);
            }
            ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            TextView text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

            text1.setText(inventory.getCode());
            text2.setText(inventory.getItem());

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }
```